# Check valid html C#

Tags: c#, html

Is there an easy way in C# to validate an html file (.htm) ?

Comment: you can use an online validator? http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: nope, it's a closed environment (BizTalk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the article  [C# Validate XHTML](http://dotnetperls.com/xhtml-validator) on Dot Net Perls.

If you are not tied to doing this in C#, then usually the best way to validate HTML is using the [W3C validation service](http://validator.w3.org/).

You could of course, write some kind of test harness in C# which pushes all your HTML through the W3C validator, if it makes sense in your case.

Comment: @PatrickPeters: Be aware that (at least according to the title) that's just for XHTML, not HTML.